# How do I use Clang from a C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, makefile, clang, llvm

My goal is to use `Clang` within a `C#` program to parse `C++` source code and build an `AST`.

If I understand correctly, I need to get `libClang` from somewhere as it is a `C` wrapper around `Clang`, and then I should be able to use the code in the following link to be able to use `libClang` from a `C#` project.

https://github.com/SimonRichards/clang-sharp

My problem is I am lost on how to install `Clang`. I have download the source from here:

https://github.com/FunkMonkey/libClang

and I tried running the makefiles through the visual studio command prompt but it just gives me an error:

`Makefile(14) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing
Stop.`

I'm quite confused as I'm not used to github and makefiles. I think the general process I need to follow is:

1. Install `LLVM` - where and what is this?
2. Install `Clang` - where is this?
3. Install `libClang` - how to run the makefiles?
4. Use SimonRichard's `clang-sharp`

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to use the project listed here, however, I was able to get up and running using http://www.nuget.org/packages/ClangSharp

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of documentation how one can get started to use LLVM / Clang. And all this documentation is pretty explicitly mentioned on the websites:

http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html
http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html
http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

And bunch of stuff around.