# How do I use c# determine the input variable's data type of a function when reading a .cpp source code?

Tags: c#, c++

In a .ccp source code, there is a few function that I have to search: say, func(...) that consist of at least 1 input variable.

E.g.

func1("abcd%s %d", name, age);
and the variable name and age had been declared previously as <string> and <int> in somewhere in the source code. By using a c# program, after using Text.ReadAllText, how do I traceback to determine the data type of a name and age variable? Because if I directly use .GetType(), it will return string which is incorrect

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            {
                foreach (string cppFile in Directory.GetFiles(file, "*.cpp", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string content = File.ReadAllText(cppFile, Encoding.UTF8);
                    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(content);
                    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int lineIndex = matches[i].Index;
                        string line = content.Substring(lineIndex, matches[i].Length);
                        Match match = regex.Match(line);
                        string inputVariables = match.Groups[1].Value;
                        if (inputVariables.Contains("%s"))
                        {
                            string[] variables = inputVariables.Split(',');
                            for (int j = 0; j < variables.Length; j++)
                            {
                                Type type = Type.GetType(variables[j]);
                                if (variables[j].GetType() == typeof(string))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(variables[j] + " is a string.");
                                    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(variables[j] + " is not a string.");
                                }
                            }
                            File.AppendAllText(outputFile, string.Format("{0}:{1}: {2}\n", cppFile, lineIndex, line));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't think regex is the appropriate tool to parse the C++ lexicon.

Comment: @gunr2171 Which library would you recommend for this task?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do software/library recommendations. See [ask].

Comment: I don't know but you are going to want some kind of parser/lexer. Try on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Don't expect this to be easy. You are probably better of using a tool to build an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) first. See [using clang/llvm from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516075/how-do-i-use-clang-from-a-c-sharp-project).

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This really smells like an X/Y problem, so it is difficult to recommend something without knowing the actual goal.

Comment: @JonasH Using C# to trace the data type of a function's input variable in a C++ source code.

Comment: Sure, but what is the *actual goal*. Why do you care about the function's input variables? If you want to ensure they are correct, just compile the code with a c++ compiler.  Some kind of interop? But that would likely be very difficult to do automatically.

Comment: @JonasH Because the C++ source code scale is too big, and the function I mentioned was called multiples time, some of the input's data type might not be correct (such as it should be in <char> instead of <string>, but the strange thing is that it can be compiled successfully and the program might crash when passing by the faulty line. So I want to write a new C# program to detect all the data type of the input variable.

Comment: 1. Check compiler warnings, or turn up warnings as much as possible. That will likely reveal most suspicious things that the compiler can determine. 2. Use some third party code analysis tool, that might reveal even more incorrect behavior. 3. Do something like add a better overload for incorrect arguments, and use `#pragma deprecated` to cause it to fail compilation. I'm not a c++ programmer, so I can't say exactly what you should do, but writing a c++ parser in C# is likely not the way to go.